# Modify pandas dataframe in python based on multiple rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a DataFrame in Pandas / Python, each row has an ID (that is not unique), I would like to modify the dataframe to add a column with the secondname for each row that has multiple matching ID's.

```
Starting with:

   ID Name  Rate
0   1    A  65.5
1   2    B  67.3
2   2    C  78.8
3   3    D  65.0
4   4    E  45.3
5   5    F  52.0
6   5    G  66.0
7   6    H  34.0
8   7    I   2.0

Trying to get to:

   ID Name  Rate Secondname
0   1    A  65.5       None
1   2    B  67.3       C
2   2    C  78.8       B
3   3    D  65.0       None
4   4    E  45.3       None
5   5    F  52.0       G
6   5    G  66.0       F
7   6    H  34.0       None
8   7    I   2.0       None
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


mydict = {'ID':[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7],
             'Name':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'],
             'Rate':[65.5,67.3,78.8,65,45.3,52,66,34,2]}

df=pd.DataFrame(mydict)

df['Newname']='None'

for i in range(0, df.shape[0]-1):
    if df.irow(i)['ID']==df.irow(i+1)['ID']:       
        df.irow(i)['Newname']=df.irow(i+1)['Name']
```

Which results in the following error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
df.irow(i)['Newname']=df.irow(i+1)['Secondname']
C:\Users\L\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:664:     SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
self.loc[key] = value
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function `f`, which use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
def f(x):
    #print x
    x['Secondname'] = x['Name'].shift(1).combine_first(x['Name'].shift(-1))
    return x

print df.groupby('ID').apply(f)
   ID Name  Rate Secondname
0   1    A  65.5        NaN
1   2    B  67.3          C
2   2    C  78.8          B
3   3    D  65.0        NaN
4   4    E  45.3        NaN
5   5    F  52.0          G
6   5    G  66.0          F
7   6    H  34.0        NaN
8   7    I   2.0        NaN
```

You can avoid `groupby` and find [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), then fill helper columns by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with column `Name`, then [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html)  and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) helper columns:

```
print df.duplicated('ID', keep='first')
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool   
print df.duplicated('ID', keep='last')
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool  
df.loc[ df.duplicated('ID', keep='first'), 'first'] = df['Name']
df.loc[ df.duplicated('ID', keep='last'), 'last'] = df['Name']
print df
   ID Name  Rate   first   last
0   1    A  65.5  NaN  NaN
1   2    B  67.3  NaN    B
2   2    C  78.8    C  NaN
3   3    D  65.0  NaN  NaN
4   4    E  45.3  NaN  NaN
5   5    F  52.0  NaN    F
6   5    G  66.0    G  NaN
7   6    H  34.0  NaN  NaN
8   7    I   2.0  NaN  NaN
```

```
df['SecondName'] = df['first'].shift(-1).combine_first(df['last'].shift(1))
df = df.drop(['first', 'l1'], axis=1)
```

```
print df
   ID Name  Rate SecondName
0   1    A  65.5        NaN
1   2    B  67.3          C
2   2    C  78.8          B
3   3    D  65.0        NaN
4   4    E  45.3        NaN
5   5    F  52.0          G
6   5    G  66.0          F
7   6    H  34.0        NaN
8   7    I   2.0        NaN
```

**TESTING**: (in time of testing solution of [Roman Kh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35384195/2901002) has wrong output)

`len(df) = 9`:

```
In [154]: %timeit jez(df1)
100 loops, best of 3: 15 ms per loop

In [155]: %timeit jez2(df2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.45 ms per loop

In [156]: %timeit rom(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.55 ms per loop
```

`len(df) = 90k`:

```
In [158]: %timeit jez(df1)
10 loops, best of 3: 57.1 ms per loop

In [159]: %timeit jez2(df2)
10 loops, best of 3: 36.4 ms per loop

In [160]: %timeit rom(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 40.4 ms per loop
```

```
import pandas as pd

mydict = {'ID':[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7],
             'Name':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'],
             'Rate':[65.5,67.3,78.8,65,45.3,52,66,34,2]}

df=pd.DataFrame(mydict)
print df


df =  pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

def jez(df):
    def f(x):
        #print x
        x['Secondname'] = x['Name'].shift(1).combine_first(x['Name'].shift(-1))
        return x

    return df.groupby('ID').apply(f)


def jez2(df): 
    #print df.duplicated('ID', keep='first')
    #print df.duplicated('ID', keep='last')
    df.loc[ df.duplicated('ID', keep='first'), 'first'] = df['Name']
    df.loc[ df.duplicated('ID', keep='last'), 'last'] = df['Name']
    #print df

    df['SecondName'] = df['first'].shift(-1).combine_first(df['last'].shift(1))
    df = df.drop(['first', 'last'], axis=1)
    return df



def rom(df):

    # cpIDs = True if the next row has the same ID
    df['cpIDs'] = df['ID'][:-1] == df['ID'][1:]
    # fill in the last row (get rid of NaN)
    df.iloc[-1,df.columns.get_loc('cpIDs')] = False
    # ShiftName == Name of the next row
    df['ShiftName'] = df['Name'].shift(-1)
    # fill in SecondName
    df.loc[df['cpIDs'], 'SecondName'] = df.loc[df['cpIDs'], 'ShiftName']
    # remove columns
    del df['cpIDs']
    del df['ShiftName']
    return df


print jez(df1)  
print jez2(df2)
print rom(df)
```

```
print jez(df1)  
   ID Name  Rate Secondname
0   1    A  65.5        NaN
1   2    B  67.3          C
2   2    C  78.8          B
3   3    D  65.0        NaN
4   4    E  45.3        NaN
5   5    F  52.0          G
6   5    G  66.0          F
7   6    H  34.0        NaN
8   7    I   2.0        NaN
print jez2(df2)
   ID Name  Rate SecondName
0   1    A  65.5        NaN
1   2    B  67.3          C
2   2    C  78.8          B
3   3    D  65.0        NaN
4   4    E  45.3        NaN
5   5    F  52.0          G
6   5    G  66.0          F
7   6    H  34.0        NaN
8   7    I   2.0        NaN
print rom(df) 
   ID Name  Rate SecondName
0   1    A  65.5        NaN
1   2    B  67.3          C
2   2    C  78.8        NaN
3   3    D  65.0        NaN
4   4    E  45.3        NaN
5   5    F  52.0          G
6   5    G  66.0        NaN
7   6    H  34.0        NaN
8   7    I   2.0        NaN
```

EDIT:

If there is more duplicated pairs with same names, use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) for creating `first` and `last` columns:

```
df.loc[ df['ID'] == df['ID'].shift(), 'first'] = df['Name']
df.loc[ df['ID'] == df['ID'].shift(-1), 'last'] = df['Name']
```

Comment: Great answer!
However, what if there are several duplicated rows? This is a question to OP, though.

Comment: Really helpful - thank you.  I implemented your `group by` which worked well.  Are there advantages to the `duplicated` method, or is it simply an alternative?  Thank you.

Comment: Answer is easy - not `groupby` is faster. I small `dataframes` 5 times and in large `dataframes` 0.6 times  as you can see in my testing `%timeit jez(df1)` vs `%timeit jez2(df2)`

Comment: Makes sense.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is sorted by ID, you might add a new column which compares ID of the current row with ID of the next row:

```
# cpIDs = True if the next row has the same ID
df['cpIDs'] = df['ID'][:-1] == df['ID'][1:]
# fill in the last row (get rid of NaN)
df.iloc[-1,df.columns.get_loc('cpIDs')] = False
# ShiftName == Name of the next row
df['ShiftName'] = df['Name'].shift(-1)
# fill in SecondName
df.loc[df['cpIDs'], 'SecondName'] = df.loc[df['cpIDs'], 'ShiftName']
# remove columns
del df['cpIDs']
del df['ShiftName']
```

Of course, you can shorten the code above, as I intentionally made it longer, but easier to comprehend.
Depending on your dataframe size it might be pretty fast (perhaps the fastest) as it does not use any complicated operations.

P.S. As a side note, try to avoid any loops when dealing with dataframes and numpy arrays. Almost always you can find a so called vector solution which operates on the whole array or large ranges, not on individual cells and rows.

Comment: Please check your answer, because it has wrong output.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I misunderstood the task a little bit.
Nevertheless, I'll leave my answer unchanged as your second solution is just great.